# Accessing typedef from the instance

Tags: c++, instance, typedef

As in stl containers, why can't we access a typedef inside the class from the class instance? Is there a particular insight into this?

---

When value_type was a template parameter it could help making more general code if there wasn't the need to specify the template parameters as in vector::value_type

Example:

```
class T {
public:
    typedef int value_type;
    value_type i;
};

T t;
T::value_type i; // ok
t.value_type i;  // won't work
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is use `decltype` to get the class first. E.g.,

`decltype(t)::value_type`

Requires C++11.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13936644/577704

Answer (score 7):

Because the typedef is just a synonym for another type. It is not an object (class's member).

And as @Neil Butterworth mentioned: "Because the . operator is the member access operator."

Comment: And because the . operator is the _member_ access operator.

Answer (score 2):

There's no good reason for using a different operator for scope resolution (`::`) than for member access (`.`) as it's never ambiguous. It's an annoyance, but it's just the way the language is.

---

Some languages do it differently though...

- C# uses `.` instead of `::`, but you still need to use the class name when accessing nested types and static members.
- D uses `.`, and `<instance>.<static nested type>` is equivilent to `<type>.<static nested type>`.

Comment: It's not just the different operator. `::` is called on the type, whereas `.` is called on the instance. But still, I too can see no good reason for not using the same.