# Can I use value_type on an instance of the vector, not on its type

Tags: c++, sizeof

while playing and trying to calculate total size of vector I tried something like

```
vector<double> vd;
auto area = vd.size()* sizeof (vd::value_type); 
//Ive seen Stepanov use area as name for this kind of size, idk if he adds the sizeof vd also to area :)
```

Unfortunately this doesnt work... 
I need to use `vector<double>::value_type` but that makes code less readable. 
Can it be made to work? I dont like `sizeof vd.front()` because it just looks ugly to write `front()` for this.
EDIT: decltype variants also fit in what I would call ugly category...

Comment: Argument to sizeof is not evaluated in the way you suggest - think of it in this way: compiler looks at what `vd.front` returns and applies sizeof at that type, there is no function call happening in here.

Comment: read what i said... i know size of is compile time... just .front() is ugly because it doesnt signal the intent... it could be .back() [.size()-1]...

Comment: my apologies for bad wording... replaced "call" with "write" it is easy to write one thing while thinking something else... :/

Answer (score 9):

I *think* [`decltype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) can be used:

```
auto area = vd.size() * sizeof(decltype(vd)::value_type);
```

as you are using `auto` I assume C++11 is permitted.

Confirmed with g++ v4.7.2 and clang v3.3.

Comment: Works perfectly. Note to eclipse CDT users: the code is underlined (warning). It's a reported false-positive. (compile OK though)

Answer (score 4):

How about a simple helper function?

```
template <typename Container>
size_t value_size(const Container &)
{
    return sizeof(typename Container::value_type);
}

[...]

vector<double> vd;
auto area = vd.size() * value_size(vd);
```

You could even overload the function so that it works with other containers such as arrays (of course, you would need to wrap `size` as well).

Ideally, the entire computation could be wrapped into a generic function:

```
template <typename Container>
size_t area(const Container &c)
{
    return c.size() * sizeof(typename Container::value_type);
}

//possible overload for arrays (not sure it's the best implementation)
template <typename T, size_t N>
size_t area(const T (&arr)[N])
{
    return sizeof(arr);
}

[...]

std::vector<double> vd;
auto vd_area = area(vd);
double arr[] = { 1., 2. };
auto arr_area = area(arr);
```

Comment: +1 Pretty sure it needs to be `sizeof(typename Container::value_type);`

Answer (score 1):

In C++11, you could use `decltype(vd[0])`:

```
auto area = vd.size()* sizeof (decltype(vd[0]));
```

But in the particular scenario, you could just write this:

```
auto area = vd.size()* sizeof (vd[0]);
```

Since the expression inside `sizeof` (and `decltype` too) will not be evaluated, both will work even if `vd` is 
empty.

Comment: @Fiktik: I was writing that too.

Comment: This is pretty much the same as `sizeof vd.front()` mentioned in the question.

Comment: @interjay: I think what the OP wants syntactically different thing. And I think `sizeof (vd[0])` is syntactically different from `sizeof (vd.front())`, though I don't know why he would find either of them *ugly*.

Comment: @interjay read my comment to original question for ugly reasoning :)